# Changing the line width/weight in Leafletr addPolylines function depending on an attribute

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I would like to display flow lines (OD-lines) using leaflet in Shiny and sofar I can successfully map all the lines I want. But I also want to change the line width so that each line will have a different linewidth depending on the attribute they have. I am trying to get the values for weight with the following code but it does not work:

```
  values <- reactive({
    test[quel==input$zelle&hr==input$std&vmitt==input$vmitt&tag==input$tag]
  })

  observe({
    anzhl <-isolate(values()[,10])
    print(anzhl[1]*2)
    str(anzhl)

    leafletProxy("zones", data = values()) %>% 
    removeShape(layerId="liID") %>% 
    addPolylines(lng=~x_coor, lat=~y_coor, stroke=TRUE, layerId="liID", color="black", weight=sum(anzhl())/100)})
```

I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Error in observerFunc: could not find function "anzhl"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: observerFunc [E:\.../server.R#118]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrong and is it ever possible to change the line widths with the values called within an interactive session.

Answer (score 3):

Read the error:

```
 Warning: Error in observerFunc: could not find function "anzhl"
```

then look at where your code mentions `anzhl`:

```
weight=sum(anzhl())/100)
```

You have `()` there, which makes R think it needs to call a function. `anzhl` is not a function, its a vector or some other data thing. If you want the sum of all the values just do `sum(anzhl)`.